# Constants across ASP.NET and C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an .aspx page which creates a column of check boxes within a table using the ID to name it as such

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="testCheck"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
  </ItemTemplate>                   
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Later in the C# portion of the code I am attempting to retrieve the value of the check box by using the following code

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gridRow.FindControl("testCheck");
```

Ideally I would like to remove the two string and hold the value in a common constant, is there any way to do this?

Comment: I've fixed this: ASP != ASP.NET. ASP is the legacy COM and VBScript approach from pre-.NET days.

Comment: Gracias! Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Are you referring to the string `testCheck`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, no, there's no way to do exactly what you want. You'll still wind up with two occurrences of the string:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="testCheck"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

and

```
public const string TestCheckName = "testCheck";
```

later

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gridRow.FindControl(TestCheckName );
```

Note that the problem isn't so much constants, as the ASP.NET markup syntax. You could do something like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="<%= TestCheckName %>"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

but that seems a little silly.

---

Ok, this doesn't work at all, and here's why:

In the declaration of the CheckBox, `testCheck` isn't just a string. If it were a string, then the `<%# %>` syntax for databinding would work. The property would be set to that string value during the `DataBinding` event.

However, the `ID` property isn't just a string property - it's what the designer and page parser will use to create a field with that name. Therefore, it must be set to a constant value.

The analogy would be having code like this:

```
protected CheckBox testCheck;
```

You can't use a string expression to create the name of a class member.

Comment: `ID="<%= TestCheckName %>"` I don't think that syntax is allowed

Comment: I'd add to this that when he declared "testCheck" in the aspx file, the codebehind can refer to the CheckBox by name for it to be compiler-checked. The only reason why he might not is if he's trying to load it dynamically, or dig into another control's members, in which case he should expose it as a property.

Comment: @Eric That is a good idea to use with the method to mitigate the issue.  I guess this is just a bad practice that you have to use with this sort of solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, a `static string` variable will do the job..

```
public static string testCheck = "testCheck";

CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gridRow.FindControl(testCheck);

<asp:CheckBox ID="<%# ClassName.testCheck %>"  runat="server" 
   AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Comment: A static string containing what exactly? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work.  I get this runtime error.... "The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value."

Comment: bzlm: Sorry dear. Can you specify the problem with the code cause I haven't check it. However, I've used a similiar code before ..

Comment: The problem *is* that you haven't check it. :) Also, this time you forgot the @ character. If you do it right, I'll get a notification about your reply. Now I just got lucky.